# Create commit message from commits in subrepo

Tags: git

**Question**: Is there a simple way to automatically extract the commit messages from a subrepo/submodule in git and create a commit message from these in the repo that contains the subrepo. I understand there is a way through some command line magic, the question is if there is some git functionality to do this.

**Context**:

I am working on a project that uses git subrepos.

`Project A` is the main project. In the folder structure of `Project A`, there is another project, `Project B`. `Project B` is itself a git repo, that is used as a subrepo (or submodule) in `Project A`. I work in `Project B`, and it falls on me to bump (update) the subrepo in `Project A`.

I do this through

```
cd /ProjectA/ProjectB
git pull
cd ../
git add .
git commit -m "Update Project B: <List of all changes since latest bump>"
git push
```

If there have been many commits since the latest bump, Writing `<List of all changes since latest bump>` becomes very tedious.

I wonder if there is a way to automatically extract the commit messages from `Project B` and create a commit message from these.

The dream solution would be to just have to write `git commit --extractMessageFromSubrepo` or something similar. I understand there is a way through some command line magic, the question is if there is some git functionality to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`git diff --submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---submoduleltformatgt) + `git commit`:

```
git diff --submodule | git commit -F-
```

`-F-` [means](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--Fltfilegt) "read from file `-`" and the file `-` means the standard input, the pipe in this case.

Comment: This is exactly, what I was looking for. Thanks, real life saver! The solution is so simple I feel stupid.